# How to start a hotspot automatically on device boot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I have an Andriod based TV box connected to the internet via ethernet. I have enabled a portable wifi hotspot (so basically it acts as a wifi router). But every time there is a power cut to this device I have to re-enable the hotspot.

Basically want to save the tethering configuration so that on a reboot the device boots in tethering mode, i.e., the last configured state.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I'm not 100% sure if all required settings could be made this way (especially as you didn't list them), but it could be accomplished using an automation tool like [Tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info), which feature to run tasks on events like `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Worth a look at least.

Comment: @JohnDoea I had a written a tasker method, don't know if wanna check it out?, I will temporarily enable it for you to see if that's what you are looking for..

Comment: [Android Samsung TAB e auto turn on Hotspot?](//android.stackexchange.com/q/201722)

Answer (score 4):

Use MacroDroid instead of Tasker, as it is more user friendly and the  UI is good.

Here are the steps:-

1. Open MacroDroid, click on the button "Add Macro", then select the trigger "Boot completed".
2. In the next screen, select the action "Turn hotspot on", then save the macro.
3. Reboot your phone.

You will see hotspot will be activated automatically after a reboot.

I used this method for an old 3g phone to create my own WiFi hotspot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html) (7 day trial available) to accomplish this:

**Objective: Auto switch-on  mobile hotspot after boot**

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering of the Task after boot:

- Go to Profiles Tab and click  "+"
- Event  → System  → Device Boot
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon as you exit, you will be prompted to link this Profile to a Task;

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select **"New Task + "**
- You can name this Task *AutoTethering* or anything.
- Click **"+"** to add new Action
- Net  → WiFi Tether (Set On)
- Press back the way all back until you exit Tasker (your profile is now saved and is ready for execution)

**Extras**: Give Tasker more priority (allow auto-start for Tasker, exclude from battery optimisations, task killers etc)

*Explanation: Soon after boot, the first action  turns on Wi-Fi tethering (note:  Tasker already has a built in **WiFi Tether variable** which is capable of handling tethering state)*

This should work. (tested)

Comment: Xavier, I cannot reply to you in comments, I am sorry. I gave you the bounty.

Comment: @JohnDoea That's okay BTW thanks for bounty!

Answer (score 2):

The previous 2 answers use Macrodroid and Tasker. To accomplish the same process with [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate), do the following:

1. Add the "Broadcast receive" block. Click on it, in the section, select "Boot complete". Click "Done".
2. Add the "Wi-Fi hotspot set state" block. Click on it and select "On". Click "Done".
3. Link the blocks. Clcik on the check mark at the top. Give your flow a name and the necessary permissions.
4. In the settings, enable "Run on system startup".

Your flow will look like the following image:

[image: IMG:]

When the device restart, the hotspot will also automatically starts.