# Automation - unable to turn hotspot on

Tags: wifi-hotspot, automation, 8.1-oreo, macrodroid

I am using a device running on AOSP 8.1

Recently I wanted to automatically turn hotspot on when device boots but Macrodroid is unable to do so

Help required!

Comment: Please mention what you did in your macro- that would make it a better question

Comment: I though you'd figured out as you mentioned in your previous [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190201/209414) anyway you can still try the [tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188650/209414) method if need be :)

Comment: Actually after answering that question I wanted to do same on Oreo but as google has changed Tethering API methods none of the apps whether be Tasker or Macrodroid are unable to do so.

Comment: Use Automate app.. It's 1000 times efficient and light-weight than mocrodroid. It has tons of options unlike macrodroid.. I too use it everyday..  =)

Answer (score 0):

A rooted device has likely been required since Android 7, where it begun to cause DHCP issues otherwise, since Android 8.1 certainly. Earlier it depended on the device manufacturer or carrier. [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackoverflow) has a [Wi-Fi hotspot set state](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/wifi_ap_set_state.html) which should work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to start your hotspot after booting/rebooting using Macrodroid:

1. Select Device Boot in the Triggers section.
2. In the Actions section. select Hotspot On/Off. A message/notification will appear, press OK, select Enable Hotspot.
3. Give the macro a name, then save it.

**Note:** I found that it's better to test the macro before rebooting for it to work as intended; not testing did not start the hotspot after rebooting the phone. The macro has been tested on a rooted Lineage 14.1 and non-rooted Android 8.1.