# Android Samsung TAB e auto turn on Hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Is there a way to automatically turn on the hotspot when my samsung tab e starts up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html) (7 day trial available) to accomplish this or [Macrodroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190201/209414) (free up to 5 macros)

**Objective: Auto switch-on  mobile hotspot after boot**

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering of the Task after boot:

- Go to Profiles Tab and click  "+"
- Event  → System  → Device Boot
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon as you exit, you will be prompted to link this Profile to a Task;

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select **"New Task + "**
- You can name this Task *AutoTethering* or anything.
- Click **"+"** to add new Action
- Net  → WiFi Tether (Set On)
- Press back the way all back until you exit Tasker (your profile is now saved and is ready for execution)

**Extras**: Give Tasker more priority (allow auto-start for Tasker, exclude from battery optimisations, task killers etc)

*Explanation: Soon after boot, the first action  turns on Wi-Fi tethering (note:  Tasker already has a built in **WiFi Tether variable** which is capable of handling tethering state)*

This should work. (tested)